# Should I need key for nullable elements in React?

Tags: reactjs

As [the official React guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) said, we need to give `key` Prop to elements in an array in order to reduce re-mount in reconciliation when some elements are changed.

According to this thinking, we need to give `key` to nullable elements as well, like the following.

```
const Component = ({ isVisible }) => {
  const nullableElement = isVisible ? <div key="NEED_KEY_1" /> : null;

  return (
    <main>
      <header />
      {nullableElement}
      <footer key="NEED_KEY_2" />
      <MyCustomComponent key="NEED_KEY_3" />
    </main>
  );
};
```

I think ... `nullableElement` and subsequent elements will be re-mounted depending on `nullableElement` because React cannot detect indices of them like as elements in an array (without keys). Especially in the root element affects performance when re-mounting child elements, so I think it's necessary to give `key` .

However, I cannot find any posts to explain it. Do I misunderstand?

---

**P.S.**

I understand that the reason React requires `key` Prop for elements in an array is so that if a particular element changes, it will re-mount the element instead of all elements in the array. For example, in an array with 50 elements without `key` , if only the 15th element is changed, all elements after the 15th element will be re-mounted. With the key, React can detect that no changes except the 15th element, thus reducing the number of re-renders.

```
// If `key` isn't given to elements in an array...
<ul>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li> <-- Changed!!
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li> <-- Remounted!!
  <li>...</li> <-- Remounted!!
  <li>...</li> <-- Remounted!!
  <li>...</li> <-- Remounted!!
  <li>...</li> <-- Remounted!!
</ul>


// So (I think) we need to give.
<ul>
  <li key="1">...</li>
  <li key="2">...</li> <-- Changed!! (but detected that key="2" is changed)
  <li key="3">...</li>
  <li key="4">...</li>
  <li key="5">...</li>
  <li key="6">...</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li key="1">...</li>
  <li key="2">...</li> <-- Remounted!!
  <li key="3">...</li>
  <li key="4">...</li>
  <li key="5">...</li>
  <li key="6">...</li>
</ul>
```

I think non-array elements have the same issues: if the 15th element is rendered or null in a non-array of 50 consecutive elements, all elements after the 15th will be re-rendered.

Comment: I think you misunderstand a bit. In this sense the React key is required when rendering an array of children. The header and footer elements won't need a React key. Also, in this case, since `nullableElement` is *just* an element, it also doesn't need a React key, when `isVisible` toggles true then a new version of `nullableElement` will be mounted/rendered since it was previously ***not*** mounted or rendered. The keys on non-array elements helps if rendering them is "expensive".

Comment: I think when `nullableElement` is rendered or null (without keys), the footer and subsequent elements will be re-mounted every time because these elements aren't given `key` , and React cannot detect indices of them. As @DrewReese said, if we omit keys on non-array elements, many elements will may be re-mounted, so I think it affects performance. Is it not necessary?

Comment: There are no arrays in your example.

Comment: If you provide a React key, React will only remount components if the key changes, otherwise it continues rendering what is there. This being said, `header` and `footer` aren't React components, they are plain HTML DOMNodes, so there is technically no React component lifecycle for them. Perhaps your contrived example doesn't quite demonstrate an issue you are asking about.

Comment: @DrewReese Okay... I collected my thoughts and just modified this post. Do I misunderstand yet?